# Will my reputation get deducted when I award a bounty

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I want to know, if I put bounty on my question then will points from my reputation be deducted when I place or when I award the bounty?

Comment: I had read this already but was not so sure if i understood everything correctly. Please dont downgrade me

Comment: From the possible dupe: *"The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded."*

Comment: `Please dont downgrade me` I shall give you a downvote for that.

Answer (score 4):

The reputation points will be deducted immediately from your total when you place the bounty.